# xml transform locator match not working as expected

Tags: .net, transform, config

I have a config file that has several database configurations like this:

```
<databases>
    <!-- core -->
    <database id="core">
    ...
    </database>
    <!-- master -->
    <database id="master">
    ...
    </database>   
    <!-- web -->
    <database id="web">
    ...
    </database>
    <!-- file system -->
    <database id="filesystem">
    ...
    </database>     
</databases>
```

and I have a transform file that looks like this:

```
<databases>
    <database id="web" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:locator="Match(id)" >
    ...
    </database>     
</databases>
```

What I am expecting to happen is that the web node would get swapped out, but what is happening is it is swapping out the first node in the list.  I have fixed it with a work around of changing the order of the nodes since the web configuration is the only one that changes for us, but I would like to know why this is happening.

Comment: Transform attribute names are case sensitive, so `locator` is ignored. Try `Locator` instead.

Comment: That did the trick!  Can't believe it was something so stupid.  Want to place it as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform attribute names are case sensitive, so `locator` is ignored. Try `Locator` instead.